# How to handle the "tel:" and "mailto:" parameters using BeautifulSoup4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I was creating a small script to crawl website of mine. This script will crawl to the website and will check if the page is broken or not based on their status code. Also, the crawler also will check if the URL have a certain word on it. The thing is, the website have this "tel:" thingies that indicate a phone number, and also "mailto:".

I've tried to add a couple if conditions to handle this sort of things.

But I'm always stuck with the error:
`InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'tel:0412345678`

Here is the snipped of my code:

````
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin, urlparse

def check_url(url):
    if url.startswith(('http://', 'https://')):
        response = requests.get(url)
        return response.status_code
    else:
        return None  # Skip unsupported schemes

def extract_url(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    urls = []

    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        href = link.get('href')
        if href:
            parsed_url = urlparse(url)
            if parsed_url.scheme != '' and parsed_url.scheme != 'tel:':
                absolute_url = urljoin(url, href)
                urls.append(absolute_url)

    return urls

def crawl(url, word):
    visited = set()
    dead_pages = set()

    def crawl_helper(url, word):  # Add the 'word' parameter
        if url in visited:
            return
        visited.add(url)

        status_code = check_url(url)
        if status_code == 404:
            dead_pages.add(url)

        if word in url:
            print(f'URL "{url}" contains "{word}".')

        urls = extract_url(url)
        for u in urls:
            crawl_helper(u, word)  # Pass the 'word' parameter

    crawl_helper(url, word)  # Pass the 'word' parameter

    return dead_pages

starting_url = 'https://google.com' # this is just a placeholder
word_to_search = 'test' # this is also a placeholder
dead_pages = crawl(starting_url, word_to_search)

for page in dead_pages:
    print(f'Dead page: {page}')```

I'm still new to BeautifulSoup but eager to learn.
````

Comment: What are you trying to do? Parse the phone number?

Comment: is this website publicly accessible? if so, what's the url?

Comment: Have you tried to `print(parsed_url.scheme)`? I've got a feeling that it may not have the `:` on the end and you should be comparing `if parsed_url.scheme != '' and parsed_url.scheme != 'tel':`, but I'm not 100%

Comment: @barry Unfortunately, the website is not publicly accessible. @0stone0 What I'm trying to do is to check all of the URLs on the site,making sure there are no 404 page, but skip any URLs that don't begin with `http://` and/or `https://` @luke I'm not sure either but I'll have a go at it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for valid url *before* using *`requests.get`* at the beginning of `extract_url` - maybe redefine it to something like:

```py
def extract_url(url):
    ## check BEFORE request
    parsed_url = urlparse(url)
    if parsed_url.scheme not in ['http', 'https']:
        return []

    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    urls = []

    ## add href=True to find_all --> no need to check if href
    for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        urls.append(urljoin(url, link.get('href') ))
```

---

If you want to also parse and check `href`:

```py
    for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        parsed_href = urlparse(href := link.get('href'))
        if parsed_href.scheme in ['', 'http', 'https']:
            urls.append(urljoin(url, href))
```

---

On another note:

- It's a bit dangerous to crawl recursively, as you are with `crawl_helper`, since you risk running into [`RecursionError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#RecursionError).
- A queue-based crawler might be better - where you loop through a list but add new URLs to that list within the loop. Even then, you risk getting stuck in an infinite loop unless you set some kind of limit on the size of the queue or on the size of `visited`. Something like

  ```py
  def crawl(url, word, max_visits=1000):
      visited = set()
      dead_pages = set()
      url_queue = [url]

      for url in url_queue:  # loop instead of recursion
          if url in visited:
              return
          visited.add(url)

          status_code = check_url(url)
          if status_code == 404:
              dead_pages.add(url)

          if word in url:
              print(f'URL "{url}" contains "{word}".')

          urls = extract_url(url)

          ## add to queue instead of recursive call
          url_queue += [u for u in urls if u not in url_queue] 

          if not len(visited) < max_visits:
              break ## stop when limit is reached


      return dead_pages
  ```

Comment: Thank you @Driftr95, I've modified my code based on yours and now it is working. And also thank you for the heads up for the RecursionError, I'll keep that in mind.